# Swift IAP purchase already bought later can use free with change purchased apple id error

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

Im building new app and have `1 service (Consumable IAP)` inside. Once users need to create account and login into app for`IAPS`.

Im trying to test it on sandbox with example test@test.com apple id later doing everything `success bought IAP`and later i add client limit have this service for my db and user logout. Later if user create new account and login into my app again try to buy this service with IAP says him `already purchased`:) and this is bug for me . how can i resolve it ? any idea.

`So with this bug`: users can change apple ids in device with purchased apple id later can use my `service free`.

I need to fix it how can i do ? any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Please clear your question: If your IAP is consumable - you should make some changes to your user account ( in backend ), something like adding some coins to his or her wallet.

Comment: If you have an issue, please describe it more detailed.